# IOS - viewWillAppear vs viewWillLayoutSubviews - NSLayoutConstraint- extension keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, nslayoutconstraint, viewwillappear

I have an NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint for my extension keyboard. It changes according to portrait and landscape mode.

- If I write it in viewWillAppear function; it works when keyboard first executed but it doesn't work for portrait->landscape or landscape->portrait situations.
- If I write it in viewWillLayoutSubviews; it doesn't work when keyboard first executed but it works properly when statusbarchanged.
- If I write it in both two functions it doesn't work.
- If I write it in updateViewConstraints function then call it in other two functions it doesn't work also.

Please help I'm trying to find a solution for hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using 
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
function instead of willLayoutSubvieww